# How to read elements of a C++ array inside EM_ASM

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

This code is wrong but it tells what I am trying to do

```
float a[2] = {1.0f, 2.0f};
EM_ASM({
    var sum = $0[0] + $0[1];
}, a);
```

What would be the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way would be

```
float a[2] = {1.0f, 2.0f};
EM_ASM_({
    var sum = getValue($0+0, 'float') + getValue($0+4, 'float');
}, a);
```

To get the `n` element in the float array do this `getValue($0 + n*4, 'float')`
If it was a double array it would be `getValue($0 + n*8, 'double')`